# Changing the columns on Magento's "Contact Us" page

Tags: magento

Is there a simple way to change the column settings on Magento's "Contact Us" page through the CMS? It seems that by default the "Contact Us" page is not listed among the other CMS pages. Do I need to override the settings via XML?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What exactly u want to do? do u want to change its layout from 2 column sidebar to 1 column?

Comment: @NirajJani Yes, exactly that!

Comment: Hello, you need to edit the contacts.xml. You need to copy that xml file into our current theme.Inside  <contacts_index_index translate="label">  add below code:- <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>

Answer (score 2):

First, determine the "layout handle" for the contact page. For u i guess it is "contacts_index_index"
U can find this in file app/design/frontend/your-package/your-theme/layout/local.xml or contact.xml

```
    <contacts_index_index translate="label">
        <label>Contact Us Form</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Contact Us</title></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="contactForm" template="contacts/form.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </contacts_index_index>
```

Change the setTemplate call to reference your template

```
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="contacts"><title>Contact Us</title></action>
    </reference>
```

Alternately, add the handle reference to your local.xml file. The local.xml file is applied last, so whatever goes in there "wins"

```
    <layout>
        <contacts_index_index>
            <reference name="root">
                <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>    
            </reference>
        </contacts_index_index>
    </layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

1. Go to CMS > Manage Pages interface in the admin panel.
2. Create the contact page here and insert the following code:

   `<!– CONTACT FORM –>
   {{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
   <!– END OF CONTACT FORM –>`
3. Click on the Design tab and change the layout to 1 column.